# Storing Tuple as a Variable (QComboBox)

Tags: python, string, combobox, tuples

### My project has multiple combobox drop downs, where the user's selection of the first drop down dictates the output of the next.

**Example:**

```
first_dropdown = 'Colored Pencil'
colors = "Black", "Blue", "Brown", "Green", "Grey", "Yellow", "White"

self.example = QComboBox()
self.example.addItem(first_dropdown, [colors])
```

### When I do this, I get the following error:

```
TypeError: index 0 has type 'tuple' but 'str' is expected
```

> The program executes without errors if instead of using the variable
> 'colors', I simply list the entire tuple ("Black", "Blue", etc.)

### How can I store the tuple as a variable and still use it in my program? Is this possible?

### Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you do this:

```
[colors]
```

you would get this:

```
[('Black', 'Blue', 'Brown', 'Green', 'Grey', 'Yellow', 'White')]
```

the function needs a tuple made of strings not a list of a tuple of strings.
you can do a simple fix by writing:

```
tuple(colors)
```

Comment: That's it! I knew it had to be something simple that I was overlooking. Thank you!